# Reading large MSSQL tables from SAS efficiently

Tags: sas

I'm working with some rather large tables in SQL Server (over 47,000 MB) and have explored ways to import the data into SAS quicker.

I started off with the following code which takes a long time:

```
  LIBNAME SQL ODBC DSN='SQL Server' user=EMTCED pw=HdPS1eMtc9 schema=dbo; 

  data ED_TAT;
  set sql.ED_TAT_Master;
  run;
```

In doing a little bit of research, I found that (BULKLOAD=yes BL_METHOD=CLILOAD) options should provide some relief; however, when adding this to my code, I get the following error.

```
  LIBNAME SQL ODBC DSN='SQL Server' user=EMTCED pw=HdPS1eMtc9 schema=dbo; 

  data ED_TAT (BULKLOAD=yes BL_METHOD=CLILOAD);
  set sql.ED_TAT_Master;
  run;


  ERROR 22-7: Invalid option name BULKLOAD.
```

Is there something I'm missing or another option that will work better? Thanks!

Comment: Terminology quibble. Since you are running SAS code you are downloading the data from SQL Server.  If you were using SQL Server code to create SAS datasets you would possibly being uploading to SAS. But really you would be exporting from SQL Server into SAS files.

Comment: BULKLOAD is only for uploads from SAS into the remote database. It does not apply to SAS datasets.  That syntax could only work if you were somehow using some external database for the libref that your one level names are written to.

Comment: @Tom thanks for the input, are you aware of option I can research to get the SQL table into SAS more efficiently?

Comment: Define long time ? Does it complete ? Do you stop the transfer ? How many rows and columns ?  Are there lots of wide SQL Server varchar columns that turn into SAS char columns ? Can you post Proc CONTENTS output for sql.ED_TAT_Master ? Do you network speed to SQL server ? What is your SAS platform ?

Comment: 800MB isn't big. What is slow to you? If you're having issues with a file that size, that's a network problem more than anything. Also, why download the file in the first place, no option to work with it from the server directly?

Comment: @Reeza, sorry I misspoke, the table is actually 47,000MB - 800 MB was the index size. Importing the file was taking upwards of 2 hours. Confused by what you mean work with it from the server directly - thanks!

Comment: Well, you can leave the file on the server unless you need every single record. What does the rest of your code do? If you show some of that we can offer alternative suggestions but genuinely not sure why you're even downloading the whole file. That being said, I used to find a 30GB file takes about 20 minutes to process on the server compared to hours on a desktop.

Comment: Thanks @Reeza, the file contains records for the past 4 years, I'm interested in only the past 2 years so I do not need every single record. What I posted above is the full extent of my code. If possible, I would love not to have to import the whole file but I'm not sure how to do that. Essentially, all I would like to do is import the last 2 years for records from the SQL serve into SAS so I can run analyses on said data. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Add a filter in then for starters so you're only pulling the two years you need. `where year(datepart(dateTImeVaraible)) in (2017, 2018);` is an example to add to your data step. This assumes your dates are stored as datetimes on the server.

Comment: How much RAM is available to your SAS client ? Analytic procedures may require or perform best when all data is in-memory. Nominally, 2 years might require 24GB just for data, so you system should probably want 32+ GB.  Many descriptive statistics can be computed SQL Server side and not require the base data being put into SAS data sets.

Comment: Two hours for a 47GB db pull seems decent to me.  My guess would be any further limitations are being caused by network / database limitations.  You could try pulling the data in smaller chunks and appending them together after (although as it looks like you're pulling from a single table without joins this trick may not help). It's possible that your company also has network security tools that process all network traffic resulting in a (hard to quantify) slow down.  The compress option that Nickolay mentions below will definitely help a little if compression isn't already enabled by default.

Answer (score 2):

`BULKLOAD=yes` is for uploading data **from** SAS. Reading data into SAS should not require special flags.

47 GB in two hours seems slow, but I'm not sure if you'll find someone who's willing to help you troubleshoot it in an online forum. Did you try to find the bottleneck? Do you have enough network bandwidth? Does querying the same table in MSSQL work faster? Do you see the SAS process max out the CPU or wait for I/O?

If we treat the transfer speed as a given, you can try reducing the amount of data downloaded:

- filter the rows with `where` as [suggested by @Reeza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56808691/uploading-sql-tables-into-sas-more-efficiently#comment100176069_56808691)
- `keep` only the columns you need
- or use the [SQL Pass-through facility](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/63647/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001370553.htm) to process the data without reading it into SAS or to pre-process data on the SQL Server and further reduce the amount of data you have to download.

You may see bad performance if you have lots of `varchar` columns: SAS character columns are fixed length, so the SAS process will end up writing lots of null bytes unless you set COMPRESS=yes on your output data set. I'm not sure, but it might have effect on the network too, so you could try using `substring()` in the SQL pass-though to limit the amount of data SAS will have to process.

Comment: I found that running                                                                                                   'proc sql;
create table new as select * from sql.table1;
quit;'                                                                                                                             
 is faster than                                                                                                   
data new;
set sql.table1;
run;

Comment: @Raven huh, I wouldn't expect that, thanks for sharing!